# BinarySerializer.Serialize Exception: Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, .net, iis-6

I am actually getting a variety of BinarySerializer exceptions such as:

- BinarySerializer.Serialize Exception:  Index was outside the bounds
  of the array.
- BinarySerializer.Serialize Exception: The internal array cannot
  expand to greater than Int32.MaxValue elements.
- BinarySerializer.Serialize Exception: Type 
  'USC.GISResearchLab.Geocoding.Core.ReferenceDatasets.Sources.Implementations.Op
  enAddressPoints'
  in Assembly
  'Tamu.GeoInnovation.Geocoding.Core.ReferenceDatasets.FeatureSources,
  Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked
  as serializable.

Here is the method being called:

```
try
        {

            string databaseName = ((IUserManagableBatchServiceManagableWebApplicationState)WebApplicationState).DatabaseManager.GetDatabaseNameFromGuid(databaseGuid);
            int databaseId = ((IUserManagableBatchServiceManagableWebApplicationState)WebApplicationState).DatabaseManager.GetDatabaseIdFromGuid(databaseGuid);
            string tableName = ((IUserManagableBatchServiceManagableWebApplicationState)WebApplicationState).DatabaseManager.GetTableNameFromGuid(tableGuid);
            int tableId = ((IUserManagableBatchServiceManagableWebApplicationState)WebApplicationState).DatabaseManager.GetTableIdFromGuid(tableGuid);
            int userId = ((IUserManagableWebApplicationState)WebApplicationState).UserManager.GetUserIdFromGuid(userGuid);

            string sql = "";
            sql += " INSERT INTO Processes ";
            sql += " (";
            ...<many column and value fields here that should not be relevant to error>
            sql += " )";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql);

            cmd.Parameters.Add(SqlParameterUtils.BuildSqlParameter("args", SqlDbType.VarBinary, BinarySerializer.Serialize(args)));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(SqlParameterUtils.BuildSqlParameter("geocoderConfiguration", SqlDbType.VarBinary, BinarySerializer.Serialize(configuration)));  

            IQueryManager qm = WebApplicationState.QueryManager;
            qm.AddParameters(cmd.Parameters);
            qm.ExecuteNonQuery(CommandType.Text, cmd.CommandText, true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string msg = "Error InsertProcess Method2: " + ex.Message;
                throw new Exception(msg, ex);
            }
        }
```

I am unable to reproduce the issue locally and after considerable time debugging was unable to find any issues as described. What's odd is recycling the application pool in IIS resolves the issue and the process is able to be started with no errors. It then pops up again later and seems to be occurring more often now. I haven't been able to find anything relevant in the log files unless I'm just missing something. I'm sure this is an obvious issue to most, but application pools are definitely not my forte. If anyone can point me in the right direction for a solution or better debugging it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the BinarySerializer class:

```
 public class BinarySerializer
    {

        public static byte[] Serialize(object o)
        {

            byte[] ret = null;
            try
            {
                if (o != null)
                {
                    if (o.GetType().IsSerializable)
                    {
                        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

                        bf.Serialize(ms, o);
                        ret = ms.ToArray();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Exception("BinarySerializer Exception: object is not serializable");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception("BinarySerializer.Serialize Exception: " + e.Message, e);
            }
            return ret;
        }
```

Comment: On the other hand, all your errors are clear. First (3), you will not be able to serialize object not marked `[Serializable]`. (2) - your object is too long for `int`. (1) - you trying to access array index that don't exist. Did you tried to actually **debug** your code? I can tell you so much - this is not pool issue. The issue is that you have not tested your app well. You never took it through "data scenarios" it goes through on the server.

Comment: I guess that's the confusing part. This app has been working as is for quite a few years now with very few changes. I am curious as to how you know it's in the configuration serializer and not the args? I have debugged it numerous times and both these objects have no issues and everything processes fine. I can run the same batch process over and over without problem, then all of a sudden the Nth time it's run I get one of the above errors. The inconsistency and sporadic nature of the error and the fact recycling the pool seemed to resolve it is what led me to believe a possible pool issue.

Comment: The configuration is derived from dozens of methods on numerous pages and would not be feasible to post, hence the missing code. Considering the exact same steps, same file being run produces the error only occasionally is why I didn't believe it to be a configuration issue. I've also edited the question to include the binaryserializer class.

Comment: Off the gate, I can tell that you have memory leaks there - your memory stream is not closed after use

Comment: The BinarySerializer is actually a class that was written long before I got here by someone much more knowledgeable than I. I thank you for pointing that out and will be sure to scour remaining classes in the code for similar leaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I see your code I think, I know what happens for your case #3

> BinarySerializer.Serialize Exception: Type 'USC.GISResearchLab.Geocoding.Core.ReferenceDatasets.Sources.Implementations.Op enAddressPoints' in Assembly 'Tamu.GeoInnovation.Geocoding.Core.ReferenceDatasets.FeatureSources, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable

Consider this code

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass 
{
    public SubClass Child {get; set;}

    //[Serializable] //-- not serializable
    public class SubClass 
    {
        public int Id {get; set;}
        public string Name {get;set;}
    }
}
```

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var c = new MyClass();
        c.Child = new MyClass.SubClass();
        byte[] bytes;
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(stream, c);
            bytes = stream.ToArray();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Success");
     }
}

Right now it will not succeed. But if you un-comment `[Serializable]` in child class it will. In your code you check the parent class for 'serializable' here

```
if (o.GetType().IsSerializable)
```

But what about children? It seem that you expect some objects come as not-serializable. In this case you need to recursively check class property hierarchy for any properties that are classes, are also serializable.

**Suggestion:**

Refactor your `Serialize` method

```
public static byte[] Serialize(object o)
{

    if (o != null) return null;
    if (o.GetType().IsSerializable)
        throw new Exception("BinarySerializer Exception: object is not serializable");

    byte[] ret = null;

    try
    {
        using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            bf.Serialize(ms, o);
            ret = ms.ToArray();
            ms.Close(); 
        }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception("BinarySerializer.Serialize Exception: " + e.Message, e);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

your case #2

> BinarySerializer.Serialize Exception: The internal array cannot expand to greater than Int32.MaxValue elements

simply indicates that your serialization is too massive.

your case #1

> BinarySerializer.Serialize Exception: Index was outside the bounds of the array

also related to objects too big.

One thing though... some of these issues were bugs in framework. You seem running on older framework if this is IIS6

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer. I think you may be correct with the #3 issue and will implement your refactor suggestion asap. The other two are more bothersome since reducing the configuration simply isn't an option. I may look into breaking it into multiple configurations and will definitely be updating IIS. Many thanks!